# Pyside2 trigger messagebox from button click closes whole application

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyside, pyside2

i want to trigger a `messagebox` from a button click without closing the entire application, I managed to do this in my previous project, but this time, the behavior is really unexpected. as soon as I clicked `ok` or the cross sign on the `messagebox`, the app also closing too without any error. here's the minimal example

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.set_and_load_ui()

    def set_and_load_ui(self):
        self.ui = QUiLoader().load('main.ui', self)

    def trigger_messagebox(self):
        self.messagebox()

    def messagebox(self,x=""):
        msg = QMessageBox(self)
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        msg.setText("{}".format(x))
        msg.setInformativeText("test")
        msg.setWindowTitle("test")
        msg.exec_()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWindow = MainWindow()
mainWindow.ui.show()
# mainWindow.trigger_messagebox() #this is fine
mainWindow.ui.mainmenuButton.clicked.connect(lambda: mainWindow.trigger_messagebox()) #this is not fine
exit_code = (app.exec_())
```

just to check, if the messagebox itself is causing the problem, I tried to call it directly on my code, but turns out it just fine, but not when I tried to trigger it by a button click

Comment: Is the ui file a main window?

Comment: yes, it is a UI file for the main window. so are you saying that the UI file can affect this kind of behavior?, in my previous project I didn't load the UI file, instead I convert it to a python file first, which look really messy and seems like a bad practice

Comment: No, it's not a bad practice. A bad practice is *modifying* those files. The problem is that QUiLoader loads the widget as a *child* of the given parent: you're practically loading a QMainWindow *into* a QMainWindow, which is unsupported.

Comment: so is it best to convert every UI generated by Qt Designer or do we just need to convert the main window one?, let's say I created another widget that I want to be added into my app, should I convert it into a python file first? (to be imported later in my app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the fact that QUiLoader loads the UI using the parent given as argument, and since the UI is already a QMainWindow, you're practically loading a QMainWindow into another, which is unsupported: QMainWindows are very special types of QWidgets, and are intended to be used as *top level widgets*.

It's unclear to me the *technical* reason for the silent quit, but it's certainly related to the fact that the loaded window actually has a parent (the `MainWindow` instance), even if that parent is not shown (since you're showing the `ui`).

Unfortunately, PySide doesn't provide a way to "install" a UI file to an existing instance unlike PyQt does (through the `uic.loadUi` function), so if you want to keep using PySide there are only two options:

1. do not use a main window in Designer, but a plain widget ("Widget" in the "New Form" dialog of Designer), load it using `QUiLoader` and use `setCentralWidget()` (which is *mandatory*, since, as the documentation also [notes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework), "creating a main window without a central widget is not supported"):

   ```
    self.ui = QUiLoader().load('main.ui', self)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.ui)
   ```

   The downside of this approach is that you cannot use the main window features anymore in Designer (so, no menus, status bar, dock widgets or toolbars).
2. use pyside-uic to generate the python code and use the multiple inheritance method to "install" it; the following assumes that you exported the ui file as `mainWindow.py`:

   ```
    from mainWindow import ui_mainWindow

    class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, ui_mainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
            self.setupUi(self)
            # no "set_and_load_ui"
            self.mainmenuButton.clicked.connect(self.trigger_messagebox)

        # ...

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    exit_code = (app.exec_())
   ```

   As you can see, now you can access widgets directly (there's no `ui` object). The downside of this approach is that you must remember to *always* generate the python file everytime you modify the related ui.